# How do I finish this method which finds largest integer in an array passed as a parameter?

Tags: arrays, count

I'm stuck with this method which should "find the largest integer in an array passed as a parameter and also output the count of the maximum value", not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

```
public class q3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arraY = {20, 20, 10, 19, 1, 4, 25, 19, 1, 11, 15, 11, 29, 27, 7, 22, 14, 26, 2, 6, 18};
    findMax(arraY);
}

public static void findMax(int[] arraY) {

    int max_value = arraY[0];
    int countMax = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arraY.length; i++) {
        if (arraY[i] > max_value) {
            max_value = arraY[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < arraY.length; i++) {
            if (arraY[i] == max_value) {
                //System.out.println(array[i]);
                //System.out.println(max_value);
                countMax++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The maximum value is: " + max_value);
    System.out.println("The count is: " + countMax);

}
}
```

edit: was an issue with scope, have rearranged the formatting and it now returns the correct result
code updated below

```
public class q3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arraY = {20, 20, 10, 19, 1, 4, 25, 19, 1, 11, 15, 11, 29, 27, 7, 22, 14, 26, 2, 6, 18};
    //int[] arraY = {30, 9, 20, 9};
    findMax(arraY);
}
public static void findMax(int[] arraY) {
    int max_value = arraY[0];
    int countMax = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arraY.length; i++) {
        //System.out.println(arraY[i]);
        if (arraY[i] > max_value) {
            max_value = arraY[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arraY.length; i++) {
        if (arraY[i] == max_value) {
            //System.out.println(arraY[i]);
            //System.out.println(max_value);
            countMax++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The maximum value is: " + max_value);
    System.out.println("The count is: " + countMax);
}
}
```

Comment: What does not work? What have you tried to fix that?

Comment: it should be outputting: 
The maximum is: 29
The count is: 1
I have been going through the findMax method adding print statements to isolate the problem, I suspect it may be in the scope but I have been working on this for quite a long time without any progress

Comment: And what happens instead?

Comment: thanks for your help but I have solved it now, will update code above